# wsimport - Imported schema with no namespace ==> package with name 'generated'

Tags: java, xsd, jaxb, jax-ws, wsimport

I created a Web Service which has a WSDL importing a schema(let's call it SCHEMA A) file which has no target namespace in it. It defines it's own types but also imports other schemas.

So when the JAXB bindings were created the package given to the types coming from SCHEMA A was "generated". For the schemas imported the packages were fine. Is there a way to customize this? I mean when I use -p it tries to add all types in the same package and there are conflicts.

This is not what I expected. Is there a way to assign different packages to different namespaces...even if that specific schema has no target namespace?

The ideal was to find a way to assign a package I want for the specific SCHEMA A.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can do this with a JAX-WS [binding customization](http://jax-ws.java.net/nonav/2.1.2/docs/customizations.html), specifically a [package customization](http://jax-ws.java.net/nonav/2.1.2/docs/customizations.html#2.1_Package_customization). This lets you specify package names for specific namespaces, or specific nodes in the schema document.  It can get a bit complex - the syntax is baroque, at best - but stick with it, it does work.